# Link react_native_tracking_transparency (arm64) 0.2 seconds * Undefined symbol: _RCTRegisterModule

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to run my react-native project in Xcode(ios) and I am faced with this error (run in real iPhone) :

## Link react_native_tracking_transparency (arm64) 0.2 seconds * Undefined symbol: _RCTRegisterModule**

My project can run on Android, but on iOS, it could not run.
I should mention that neither can run in the simulator nor on a real iPhone, and the strange thing is that I can archive it and I can do it via test flight. When I install the test flight application it works well, but I can not run the project.

I uninstall ***react_native_tracking_transparency *** to see if the error is related to this package but as soon as I uninstall that, the same error*(Undefined symbol: _RCTRegisterModule) *happens but with another package (react_native_spinkit), and I continue to uninstall also SpinKit package and again the error happens with another package.
Also, it could not run in the previous Xcode version (13), when I updated my Xcode (14.1) for the first time after updating Xcode the app could run in Xcode, but then again the error happened and could not run the app.

my system config:
Mac mini,chip apple M1,macOS:Ventura 13

Xcode: 14.1

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.68.1

I tried different solutions but none of them works for me.
Thanks in advance for any help from you.

Answer (score 0):

updating about solutions:

I finally fixed the problem these are the steps:
1)rm -fr node_modules/
2) rm -fr yarn.lock
3)cd ios
4) rm -fr Pods
5)rm -fr podfile.lock
6)rm -fr YOURPOJECT.xcworkspace
7) cd ..
8) yarn install
9) cd ios
10) pod install
11)pod update ( this is the magic, updating the pod fixes the issue)

I explained in detail maybe somebody is a beginner